# In tcsh, cat file1.txt > file2.txt doesn't work if file exists

Tags: shell, cat, tcsh

The documentation says that if destination file exists it will be overwritten. But it doesn't overwrite. Instead it gives me the error message "file2.txt: File exists."

Comment: As an aside -- using csh is [a bad idea](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt), and I strongly advise that you *don't*.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> If  the shell variable noclobber is set, then the file must not exist or be a character special file (e.g., a terminal or `/dev/null`) or an error results.  This helps prevent accidental destruction of files.  In this case the `!` forms can be used to suppress this check.

That is:

```
cat file1.txt >! file2.txt
```

See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-41